# Downloading STAR on MAC OS Mojave

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to download STAR for RNA seq. After I installed gcc 8.2, and inputting this command on terminal

```
make STARforMacStatic CXX=/Users/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8
```

It keeps responding

```
make: *** No rule to make target `STARforMacStatic'.  Stop.
```

How do I get this work?

Answer (score 3):

These days, you really don't need to be downloading and manually managing things like gcc or building STAR.  Instead, install [Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html) (i.e., Miniconda + `bioconda` and `conda-forge` channels), then it's just a matter of

```
conda install star
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use brew (like sugest README file), this path (CXX=/Users/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8).

Copy and paste command from README file:

```
$make STARforMacStatic CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++-8
```

Path to brew files is /usr/local/Cellar. Mine:

```
alex@vosjod:/usr/local/Cellar$ ls -1
adns
aom
bash-completion
bashmarks
ctags
erlang
exiftool
ffmpeg
fontconfig
freetype
frei0r
fribidi
gdbm
gettext
git
gmp
gnupg
gnutls
go
icu4c
jpeg
...
```